# List View item is taking the whole text

Tags: android, xml

Sorry, As this is already asked several times. But none of these working out for me. List Items are showing all the contents from the EditText. I just want to keep the texts in a line in ListView.

[image: Here is the visualization.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should add those attributes for `itemView` which is inflated in your adapter.

Comment: which adapter you are using? `ArrayAdapter` or your custom-adapter?

Comment: Using ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create file single_line_list_item.xml in your layout folder and Paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

then create your array adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_line_list_item, items);
```

Comment: Worked, Saved my day. Is it possible explain why my ellipse, single line command aren't working from the parts of code I given in question? That would Help a lot.

Comment: ListView has not any property named singleLine ;because items in listview are imported from another xml file that developer specifies.